# How to project an item in an array to the top level and also fetch only the matched objects in the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Currently this is an example of a dataset in my `salesOrder` collection

```
{
    "totalCost": 4,
    "salesOrderRef": "s4",
    "customerRef": "c10",
    "date": "2021-06-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "etd": "2021-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "delivered": true,
    "paid": false,
    "inventory": [{
        "sku": "i3",
        "quantity": 1,
        "priceEa": 2,
        "discount": "0"
    }, {
        "sku": "i2",
        "quantity": 2,
        "priceEa": 2,
        "discount": 2
    }]
}
```

How do I get it to match

```
{
    "salesOrderRef": "s4",
    "customerRef": "c10",
    "sku": "i3",
    "quantity": 1,
    "priceEa": 2,
    "discount": "0"
}
```

if I search `sku: i3?` If there are any duplicate `sku` in the inventory array of a single `salesOrder` document, I would also like it to duplicate another result out, like

```
{
    "salesOrderRef": "s4",
    "customerRef": "c10",
    "sku": "i3",
    "quantity": 1,
    "priceEa": 2,
    "discount": "0"
},
{
    "salesOrderRef": "s4",
    "customerRef": "c10",
    "sku": "i3",
    "quantity": 3,
    "priceEa": 4,
    "discount": "0"
}
```

How could I achieve this? I tried using aggregation and filters but I'm not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this aggregation query, from what I understood this is should give you the output document you have mentioned.

```
db.collection.aggregate([

  {
    $unwind: "$inventory"
       },   {
    $project: {
    "_id" : 0,
    "salesOrderRef": 1,
    "customerRef": 1,
    "sku": "$inventory.sku",
    "quantity": "$inventory.quantity",
    "priceEa": "$inventory.priceEa",
    "discount": "$inventory.discount"
    }   
}, ])
```

Comment: Thank you alot!! Unwind was perfect, I had to further project and then match again to filter it to only ```sku: i3``` again